# UpdateGeometrySRID and low disk space

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, srid

I have imported a 508GB DB with unknown SRID with ogr2ogr, hence my geometry SRID is 900914.

Now I'd like to run

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('contours','wkb_geometry',3857);
```

However, I'm running low on disk space (~300GB left) and it seems that UpdateGeometrySRID consume everything before failing.

Is there a way to run things more progressively ?

**Edit my own question with best (easiest) answer:**

Re-run `ogr2ogr` with `-a_srs epsg:3857` option and remember it for the next time.

Comment: If you still have the original data it is probably fastest to drop the table and import again with `ogr2ogr -a_srs epsg:3857`.

Comment: It already took a week to import, so if there is something that could take one day or two ...

Comment: If only you spent a minute or two for thinking before you started the import :). Well, create a new geometry column into your table "geom_3857" and run `update table set geom_3857= ST_Transform(geom, 3857) limit 100000 offset 0` SQL may not be right, but got the idea: update in batches defined by limit and offset. After update you can delete the original geometries and free data before the next batch.

Comment: By reading http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html, isn't the last example for you `ALTER TABLE roads 
 ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 3857) USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,4326),3857) ;` Have you tried?

Comment: You may run into fragmentation and high-water mark issues by trying to add a second geometry column. When a table is that large, you really don't want it fragmented, and if it took a week to load, it's possible your server is under-powered (colleagues of mine loaded 630m rows of points w/ ~500 bytes of attributes in 20 hours several years ago)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run ogr2ogr with `-a_srs` option a next time.